# Moderncv package not working

Tags: moderncv

I'm trying to make my CV with the moderncv package for the first time... But I don't know what I'm missing and it  says "`!Unidentified control sequence \modercvcolor{blue}`" it also says that I'm missing the `\begin{document}`

Here is an example of what I'm running.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

%% ModernCV themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\nopagenumbers{}

%% Character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% Adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%% Personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resumé title (optional)}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote (optional)}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{ \textit{Grade} }{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cvitem{title}{ \emph{Title} }
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvdoubleitem{category X}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category Y}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 3}
%% ...

\bibliography{publications}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm using the native application of Latex on Mac OSX

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I use TeXmaker on Mountain Lion. After commenting out the `\photo` command, I get no error. The latest release of `moderncv` is version 1.3.0 (09 Feb 2013). Get that update via TeX Live Utility, and try running your code again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "native application of LaTeX" on OSX.

You need to install [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/) and to keep it up-to-date by launching the "Tex Live Utility" application. Your MWE doesn't generate any error on an up-to-date installation (assuming your picture is named `picture.jpg`) and the error you are getting is due to an outdated `moderncv` package.